# Load same stylesheet for front end and wp-admin

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

How can i load same style sheet for both front end and wp-admin of a wordpress site

Answer (score 3):

Use special hooks 
For Admin panel:

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts_and_styles_function');
```

For Front-end:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts_and_styles_function');
```